# Need help to fix owner, groups and user permissions in Xubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, users, ownership, administrator

Some time ago I messed up my system users and groups permissions, now I can't run **users-admin** command, the output is : **the owner of /home/vladimir/.config/ibus/bus is not vladimir!**(the owner is **root**), if I change to **vladimir** I got the same output displaying that the owner is not **root**. I can't modify anything on users and groups GUI, when I try to modify any setting
immediately open and close several windows so fast that I can't read what's going on! Appreciate some help, I have one user added long time ago.

Comment: FWIW: Backup your data, then reinstall - is probably the easiest fix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have stirred your system with a `root`stick, run GUI tools as `root`, and in general, behaved carelessly. What's the `users-admin` command? However,

To see what `root` owns in your `$HOME` directory,

```
sudo find $HOME -user root
```

and, to change them back to you,

```
sudo find $HOME -user root -print0 \
    xargs -0 -r sudo chown "$USER"
```

If `sudo` doesn't work for you, you've really broken your system. I hope you have backed up your data.

If you KNOW of a file you've messed with, find the package that provides it, and re-install that package. For example, if you've changed the permission/ownership of `/bin/su`, you could do:

```
walt@bat:~(127)$ type -p su
/bin/su
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S $(!!)
dpkg -S $(type -p su)
login: /bin/su
walt@bat:~(0)$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall login
```

But, the easiset, safest way is to backup your data, ensure that you can read your backup, reinstall the WHOLE system, and restore.

Comment: Ok, I will try to restore users-admin command and GUI to original owner and pemissions, my system works without errors and/or fails, I had restored ALMOST every thing as it was, ONLY  this issue (users-admin) is missing, sudo works gksu works ! thanks for explanation, very helpfull